# Sending spark dataset as email

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have a spark dataset that needs to be sent as an attachment to an email.
I found the below link but it explains things in scala. Can someone help me with java code for sending the dataset as an attachment to an email?

[sending-spark-dataframe-via-mail](https://medium.com/@n.suthar.online/sending-spark-dataframe-via-mail-f396b1810d89)

```
Dataset<Row> finaldataset-> This is my dataset
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try to import that library into your project & use those method as normal java ??

Comment: sorry didnt get you, which library are you specifying?

Comment: ```https://medium.com/@n.suthar.online/sending-spark-dataframe-via-mail-f396b1810d89``` - same library which you mentioned in question, have you tried including into your project ??

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ConstructDataForEmail(Dataset<Row> datasetForEmail) {
    try {

        // Saving Dataset into CSV file into a single partition
        datasetForEmail.repartition(1).write().
                format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", true).save("/tmp/output");

        //Getting Path of saved CSV file, as file is saved with name like part-0000-asgditda-yewd-yea-......csv
        Optional<File> file = Arrays.stream(FileUtil.listFiles(new File("/tmp/output")).filter(fl -> fl.getName().endsWith(".csv")).findFirst();
        String filePath = null;
        if (file.isPresent())
            filePath = file.get().getPath();
        String subject = "Subject of the Email";
        String emailBody = "Body for the Email";
        String fileName = "Meaningful name to attached File";

        //Method to send the email
        sendMail(subject, emailBody, filePath, fileName);

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        LOG.info(" Error while preparing the data to send", exp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding an explanation to your code how it works and how it answers the OP's question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).